Flask app gets a value(None) from my form before I fill it which leads to anomalies in the app
I am creating a quiz game using Flask and I tried to get the player's input using a form. I realized during testing that even when I input the right answers, the score does not update. So I printed the player's answers to the terminal and saw that for the first question, the browser automatically gives the player a value of NONE, which creates a mismatch between the player's answer and the correct answer.
@app.route("/play", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def play():
    score = 0
    question = ''
    correct_answer = ''
    msg = ''
    still_playing = True

    while still_playing:
        # Randomly select a question type
        easy_atomic_number = random.randint(1, 31)
        easy_element = p_dict[easy_atomic_number]
        hard_atomic_number = random.randint(31, 60)
        hard_element = p_dict[hard_atomic_number]

        if score < 3:
            question = f"easy: What is the name of the element with the symbol {easy_element['Symbol']}? "
            correct_answer = easy_element['Element']
        else:
            question = f"Hard: What is the symbol for the element {hard_element['Element']}?"
            correct_answer = hard_element['Symbol']

        if request.method == 'POST':
            user_answer = request.form.get('answer')
            if user_answer == correct_answer:
                score += 1
                msg = 'You are correct'
            else:
                msg = f'Incorrect, correct answer is {correct_answer}'
            print(score)
            print(user_answer)
            print(correct_answer)
        return render_template('play.html', score=score, question=question, correct_answer=correct_answer,
                               msg=msg)

and this is what i get from the terminal. I am fairly new at this, and I need help with a project for which the deadline is quickly approaching. Please, any help would be greatly appreciated. enter image description hereThanks in anticipation.
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 117-510-594
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2024 13:31:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2024 13:31:22] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2024 13:31:22] "GET /static/app.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
**0
None
Manganese**
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2024 13:31:25] "POST /play HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2024 13:31:25] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2024 13:31:25] "GET /static/app.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -

relevant html code
        <div class="questions">
            <div>
                <h1 class="display-4 text-primary-emphasis" >Question:</h1>
                <h1 class="display-6 text-primary-emphasis" >{{ question }}</h1>
            </div>

            <form action="{{ url_for('play') }}" method="POST">
               <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="ans" class="form-label">Answer</label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="answer" id="ans" aria-label="default input example">
                   <button type="submit" name="answer" class="btn btn-success btn-lg mt-2">Check</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <h6>{{msg}} !!!!</h6>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                SCORE <span class="badge text-bg-secondary">{{ score }}</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>


     <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
          <button class="btn btn-danger me-md-2 btn-lg" type="button">Quit</button>
          <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" type="button">Restart</button>
    </div>

